# MacBook Pro M2 missing TMSafetyNet.kext

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ventura

I'm trying to delete some files that the OS won't let me delete and someone suggested I use `bypass` in `TMSafetyNet.kext` however `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext` does not exist.

I'm on Ventura 13.3.1

Where can I find the `bypass` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly certain the `bypass` tool no longer is available and most backups are snapshots and not hard linked files on a plain filesystem. The library you mention is very much gone from where it was shipped and this is part of a larger and intentional removal of kernel extensions across the board - not a sign of a broken system on your part.

You may have to restate / re ask your question since we don't know the end goal but can let you know to let go of the tool you think will help.

The `bypass` tool only worked to remove files from Time Machine created and protected locations - not system files or other locked / protected files.